# Decrease MobileServiceClient InvokeAPI timeout

Tags: xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I'm using Xamarin to connect to Azure Mobile Services on Android and iOS. When we have a good mobile connection, everything is fine. However, when the mobile connection is slow the default timeout of 60 seconds has a negative impact on our users because it may take up to that long to indicate to the user that their action has not completed.

My question is how to decrease the timeout for InvokeAPI and MobileServiceClient?

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the default timeout of Android and iOS HttpClient.
It's not possible to set the timeout in your shared code (PCL).

Comment: Thanks. But how do you pass a httpclient object into the MobileServicesClient? Our code constructs a native handler and passes that in: `Mvx.RegisterType<IMobileServiceClient>(() => 
     {
      ICustomHttpClient customHttpClient = Mvx.Resolve<ICustomHttpClient> ();

      HttpMessageHandler handler = customHttpClient.GetNativeHandler();


      HttpMessageHandler[] handlerArray = new HttpMessageHandler[] { handler };

      return new MobileServiceClient(ApplicationConstants.ApplicationUri, ApplicationConstants.ApplicationKey, handlerArray);
     }
    );`

Comment: You cannot inject it directly into the MobileServiceClient since it is an internal class (https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/84e7d3c0a896d4434cf3da0b03f7cd4ea1d3cd83/sdk/Managed/src/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices/Http/MobileServiceHttpClient.cs). MobileServiceClient uses the platform specific HttpClient. You have to override their default timeout settings. Otherwise set Task timeout at InvokeApiAsync.

Comment: I guess my question therefore is how do you get a handle on the platform specific httpclient to override those settings?

Comment: This blog should describe how to get at the timeout information: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/08/07/httpclient-httpclienthandler-and-httpwebrequesthandler.aspx

Hope this helps!

Henrik